# Include custom tables in Report Dashboard generated by JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to customize the JMeter generated report dashboard. I am using Apache JMeter 4.0 version.
By using this command

jmeter -g test.csv -o

I am able to create a reporting dashboard. My requirement is I want to add custom tables in the report generated by JMeter( As JMeter generates Statistics, Errors, Top 5 Errors by sampler report by default).

So how can I add a new custom table in the report dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limited options to modified the reports:-

1. You can put filters on the data to be reported
2. You can include sample_variables data in the report.

Check the below links:-

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs

I think, out of the box customization is fairly limited.

Hope this helps.